# Valgrind shows blocks are definitely lost in loss record

Tags: c, binary-search-tree, hashtable, valgrind, doubly-linked-list

I can't understand why there's a memory leak in this code.

Data structures:

```
typedef struct linkedListNode_t {
   
    int value;
   
    struct linkedListNode_t* next;
    
    struct linkedListNode_t* prev;
}linkedListNode_t;

typedef struct linkedList_t {
   
    unsigned int size;
   
    struct linkedListNode_t* head;
}linkedList_t;

typedef struct hashtableEntry_t {
    
    struct linkedList_t* list;
} hashtableEntry_t;

typedef struct hashtable_t {
    
    unsigned int size;
  
    struct hashtableEntry_t** entry;
} hashtable_t;

typedef struct rbtNode_t {
   
    int value;
    
    char color;
    
    struct rbtNode_t* parent;
    
    struct rbtNode_t* left;
    
    struct rbtNode_t* right;
} rbtNode_t;


typedef struct rbt_t {
    
    unsigned int size;
    
    struct rbtNode_t* root;
    
    struct rbtNode_t* nil;
} rbt_t;
```

The free functions that i use:

```
void linkedListFree(linkedList_t* list) {
    linkedListNode_t *node = list->head;  
    linkedListNode_t *victim;
    while (node != NULL) {                 
        victim = node;      
        node = node->next;          
        free(victim);              
    }
    list->head=NULL;
    free(list);   

}

void hashtableFree(hashtable_t* hashtbl) {

    int i;


    if(!hashtbl)
        return;

    for(i=0;i<hashtbl->size;i++){
        linkedListFree(hashtbl->entry[i]->list);
        free(hashtbl->entry[i]);
        hashtbl->entry[i]=NULL;
    }


    free(hashtbl);
    hashtbl=NULL;

}

void rbtFreeNodes(rbt_t* T, rbtNode_t* x) {

    if(x == T->nil)
        return;
    rbtFreeNodes(T,x->left);
    rbtFreeNodes(T,x->right);
    
    free(x);

}

void rbtFree(rbt_t* T) {

    rbtFreeNodes(T,T->root);
    free(T);
    T = NULL;
}
```

This is the message Valgrind gives to me:

```
==28711== 76,800 bytes in 2,400 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 4 of 5
==28711==    at 0x483C7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==28711==    by 0x10A026: createRbt
==28711==    by 0x10AB76: doExperiment
==28711==    by 0x1094BA: main 
==28711== 
==28711== 1,132,800 bytes in 2,400 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 5 of 5
==28711==    at 0x483C7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==28711==    by 0x109BBE: createHashtable 
==28711==    by 0x10AA89: doExperiment
==28711==    by 0x10949D: main
```

This is my doExperiment function:

```
clock_t doExperiment(int* randomArray, const unsigned int numInsertions, const unsigned int numSearches, char* dataStructure) {

     clock_t startTime=0, endTime=0,tot = 0;

     if(strcmp(dataStructure,"hashtable")==0){
        hashtable_t *ht = createHashtable(NUM_ENTRIES);
        linkedListNode_t *nodo;

        startTime = clock();

        for(int i=0;i<numInsertions;i++){
            int randomIndex = rand() % numInsertions;
            hashtableInsert(ht,randomArray[randomIndex]);
        }


        for(int i=0; i<numSearches;i++){
             int randomIndex = rand() % numInsertions;
             nodo = hashtableSearch(ht,randomArray[randomIndex]);

        }
        endTime = clock();
        tot = endTime-startTime;
        hashtableFree(ht);
        
        
       
     }

     if(strcmp(dataStructure,"rbt")==0){
        struct rbt_t *rbt = createRbt();
        struct rbtNode_t *nodo;

        startTime = clock();

        for(int i=0;i<numInsertions;i++){
            int randomIndex = rand() % numInsertions;
            nodo = createRbtNode(randomArray[randomIndex]);
            rbtInsert(rbt,nodo);
        }

        for(int i=0;i<numSearches;i++){
            int randomIndex = rand() % numInsertions;
            nodo = rbtSearch(rbt,randomArray[randomIndex]);
        }

        endTime = clock();
        tot = endTime-startTime;
        rbtFree(rbt);
        
     }

return tot;
    

}
```

As you can see i always call the free functions but i still have memory loss.
I can't figure out where my mistake is.
Are my free functions correct? Or they don't free the data structures? Any kind of help or suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: Your question cannot be concisely answered without [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That said,ignoring the RBT for now, with your hashtable, to free all memory, you need to iterate over each bucket containing a node. The node is the head node in a list, so call your free list within your free hashtable function. After freeing the list, you would then simply free the allocated pointers that are the hashtable buckets. (and whatever else you allocate for your tree)

Comment: thank you for your answer, i'm  a bit confused, i already call the free list within the free hashtable function so i'm not understanding how should i change the function.

Comment: Compile your executable with debug information (eg `-g3`) then rerun under Valgrind. You should then have the line numbers for the allocations which should make the source(s) of the leak(s) clearer.